# Как получить доступ к методу SOAP сервиса через java?

Tags: java, soap

http://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?op=GetCursOnDate Нужно вызвать данный метод, по ссылке есть примеры SOAP request и response, как удаленно вызвать этот метод без генерации классов по wsdl и возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это же обычный HTTP POST-запрос! Используйте [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).